# Snowflake → Zapier Integration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, zapier

I'm using Zapier with Redshift to fetch data from custom queries and trigger a wide array of actions when new rows are detected from either a table or custom query, including sending emails through Gmail or Mailchimp, exporting data to Google Sheets, and more. Zapier's UI enables our non-technical product stakeholders to take over these workflows and customize them as needed. Zapier has several integrations built for Postgres, and since Redshift supports the Postgres protocol, these custom workflows can be easily built in Zapier.

I'm switching our data warehouse from Redshift to Snowflake and the final obstacle is moving these Zapier Integrations. Snowflake doesn't support the Postgres protocol so it cannot be used as a drop in replacement for these workflows. No other data source has all the information that we need for these workflows so connecting to an upstream datasource of Snowflake is not an option. Would appreciate guidance on alternatives I could pursue, including the following:

1. Moving these workflows into application code
2. Using a foreign data wrapper in Postgres for Snowflake to continue using the existing workflows from a dummy Postgres instance
3. Using custom-code blocks in Zapier instead of the Postgres integration

Comment: Does Zapier have a generic connector like JDBC, ODBC, Python, or allow you to configure one yourself?  I am not as familiar with Zapier, but I've heard its like a corporate version of IFTTT.

Comment: Zapier does have Python support, but unfortunately not JDBC or ODBC. I haven't used IFTTT but it looks interesting, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Snowflake has an API that will allow you to do what you want, but you can create a private Zapier Integration that will have all the same features and permissions as a public integration, but you can customize it for your team.

There's info about that process here: https://platform.zapier.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use a vendor solution like Census to forward rows as events to Zapier. Their free plan is pretty sizeable for getting started. More info here https://www.getcensus.com/integrations/zapier